# Angular: Getting the scope that an element was compiled with

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a `directive` with an incoming `attribute` of "contextMenuId."

In this directive I now perform:

```
contextMenu = $('[id*="' + iAttrs.contextMenuId+'"]');
```

or...

```
contextMenu = angular.element(document.querySelector('[id*="' + iAttrs.contextMenuId+'"]'))
```

*If these don't do the same thing, I would love it if someone could tell me the difference, but that's separate from my answer.*

Now, lets have a look at our `contextMenu`:

```
<ul id="exampleContextMenu" context-menu-defs="contextMenuDefs" ></ul>
```

I would like to access the array `contextMenuDefs` from the directive I mentioned earlier, yet this is from an entirely different `scope` that I do not have access to.

Can I somehow get access to the `scope` that `contextMenu` was compiled with from within my directive? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can. Can you add code of your directive where you have contextMenu?

Comment: Why are you using `$` from within an angular directive? Use the second argument passed into `link`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @tcooc The second argument to `link`? Do you mean `element`? Yea, that's a jQuery based handle to the DOM element which invoked your directive. I can't use that to invoke another element. I could instead use `angular.element(document.querySelector('[id*="' + iAttrs.contextMenuId+'"]'))`, but I thought I would go out on a limb and use jQuery for once. The `angular` way I just suggested should have better performance. I have decided to update my answer to this "angular way."

Comment: @dfsq These two directives are very convoluted and large, and I am only allowed to release so much information about how our code works (any more could get me in trouble). I thought of making a JSFiddle, but creating a working example of these two would take a lot of time, and that is something I do not have for that. I've provided enough code to receive an answer within the bounds of how I would like my answer to perform. I assume that there is an `angular` based look-up that I can perform on my `contextMenu` handle from the example I have provided, and that is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: You see, if your question was clear I wouldn't ask for details and just answered right away. But you didn't post the most important part: where `contextMenuDefs` comes from and how your directive binds/processes data. But since you can't provide more details all I can answer to "Can I somehow get access to the scope that contextMenu was compiled with from within my directive?" - yes, it's totally possible.

Comment: Where `contextMenuDefs` comes from should not matter in this answer at all! It actually makes no difference here. The only possible difference may be if we would like to suggest that angular should propagate up the parent scope tree rather than the child, in which case the answer should suggest both based on the invocation of said directive (which can be done by either). The information that you are requesting is irrelevant to the answer, unless you were suggesting to try a hack like `scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.. contextMenuDefs`, which will not work in this case. These scopes are unrelated

Comment: @dfsq In more layman's terms, the only time that the method of how my directives `bind/process` data would be relevant is if we were accessing related scopes which, as I thought was quite obvious in this case, they are not.

Comment: @dfsq I am not providing more information as the information you are requesting would narrow the effective scope of my answer. I would like for the answer to be unrelated to the topology of the scope I seek, and if the answer is dependent on said topology, I do not want it. An answer should be obtainable within the current confines of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for get scope other element:

```
angular.element("<selector as jquery>")).scope();
```

In your situation:

```
var scopeOuther = angular.element('[id*="' + iAttrs.contextMenuId+'"]')).scope();
```

Comment: No way! Thats exactly what I wanted! Let me try this. I'm so excited!